# How to get array of specific attributes values in cypress

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I have a few elements in DOM and each of them has its own attribute 'id'. I need to create a function which iterates throw all of these elements and pushes values into the array. And the happy end of this story will be when this function will give me this array with all 'id' values.

I have tried this:

```
function getModelIds() {
  let idList = [];
  let modelId;
  cy.get(someSelector).each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).invoke('attr', 'id').then(lid => {
      modelId = lid;
      idList.push(modelId);
    });
  });
  return idList;
}
```

Will be very appreciated if you help me with rewriting this code into a function which will return an array with all 'id' values.

Comment: This question would be more informative if you told readers why your code didn't work.  What did it actually do?

Answer (score 4):

You can have [a custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax):

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getAttributes',
  {
    prevSubject: true,
  },
  (subject, attr) => {
    const attrList = [];
    cy.wrap(subject).each($el => {
      cy.wrap($el)
        .invoke('attr', attr)
        .then(lid => {
          attrList.push(lid);
        });
    });
    return cy.wrap(attrList);
  }
);
```

You can use it later like this:

```js
cy.get(someSelector)
  .getAttributes('id')
  .then(ids => {
    cy.log(ids); // logs an array of strings that represent ids
  });
```